# Best approach with Jasper Report

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a requirement to generate reports in PDF and Excel format. For the same I have chosen Jasper. Now require some help from your side to identify the best approach on the same.

Note - My queries are dynamic in nature.Like in some scenario then will provide name in some scenario they will provide dates not name and in some scenario both.

Approaches I have identified are given below.

1. We can create data source and query in JRXML and execute the same.But not sure query will be dynamic or not. I am personally not prefer this approach because from java I can pass the connection from pool.
2. We can pass the query and connection both from the Java side and then Japser will execute the query.
3. We can query in java and then pass the List of bean to the Jasper for report creation.

Now need some suggestions on the best approach among above and also of any approach suggested apart from the above.

Answer (score 0):

To me, `option 3` is best. I did that previously.
For mine, I had a master report containing conditional sub-reports. To do that, I have build sub-report's `.jasper` from their `.jrxml` and passed my List of bean so that I don't have to re/compile the `.jasper` from `.jrxml` again(My master report was in `.jrxml` and condition for sub-reports where set there).
Another advantage is, you don't have to change your jasper files if you want to change your logic in query level-just leave them untouched once done.
So, I think , `option 3` is good to go.

Comment: Thanks. But in option #3 Jasper file needs to parse the collection every time. So, should we go for Option#2 that may be faster.

Comment: @Souvik, making standalone report is good mentioned in option 2. But will face complexity if you can't get all data from a single `query` to feed the report. Otherwise, that's ok. As you haven't mentioned that, I come up  with all possible options bubbled in my head.